# minimum and maximum numbers from user input

Tags: c#

I found this code for finding minimum and maximum numbers from user input.

```
using System;
    class FindMinAndMaximalNumber
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] numbers;
            bool isInteger=true;
            int minimal=int.MaxValue;
            int maximal=int.MinValue;
            Console.Write("Enter a sequence of numbers delimited with \",\":");
            numbers = (Console.ReadLine()).Split(',');

               int[] intNumbers=new int[numbers.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < (numbers.Length); i++)
            {
                isInteger = int.TryParse(numbers[i], out intNumbers[i]);
                if (isInteger==false)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isInteger)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (intNumbers[i] < minimal)
                    {
                        minimal = intNumbers[i];
                    }
                    if (intNumbers[i] > maximal)
                    {
                        maximal = intNumbers[i];
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("minimal={0}",minimal);
                Console.WriteLine("maximal={0}",maximal);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid entry! Some of the entries are not integer!");
            }
        }
    }
```

My questions are: 
 1 - Is the following code declaring an array `intNumbers` that has the size equal to the size of Array called "number"

```
int[] intNumbers=new int[numbers.Length];
```

yes or no?

2 - Check this  `TryParse` method....

```
isInteger = int.TryParse(numbers[i], out intNumbers[i]);
```

If `IsInteger` is true, then does it mean..that the value of i is stored in
`intNumbers[i]`...????
or can anyone explain this code breifly

Comment: To both your questions - yes. But the value `numbers[i]` is stored in `intNumbers[i]`, not just `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. `datatype[] arrayName = new datatype[length];`
2. The method `int.TryParse()` converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeede. In this case `TryParse` will check each element of array "numbers" and if it is a `int` datatype then it will store the value to other array. That have been done to prevent entering of not numerical values.
   So, if `IsInteger` is true then it means that all the values you entered are numbers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much SimpleVar
and Thank you soo much MegaTron
for your help.
Just last clarification
.So it means that following code is "only" declaring **the size** of the new array called "intNumbers"

**int[] intNumbers=new int[numbers.Length];**

but 
the items are stored in this new array "intNumbers" by this code(along with the for loop)

**isInteger = int.TryParse(numbers[i], out intNumbers[i]);**

each time its true and for loop is executed